# Как исправить ошибку TS2322 Property is missing in type в Angular 7?

Tags: angular2, typescript, angular, angular4, angular5

Модель:

```js
export interface PageProject {
    content: Project[];
    totalPages: number;
    totalElements: number;
    last: boolean;
    size: number;
    first: boolean;
    sort: string;
    numberOfElements: number;
}

export interface Project {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    created: string;
    updated: string;
    requests: Request[];
}
```

Диалоговое окно для создания или редактирования проекта (Названия/Описания)

```js
export class CreateEditProjectDialogComponent {

    form: FormGroup;
    project: Project;

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private projectService: ProjectService,
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CreateEditProjectDialogComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data:Project
    ) {
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            name: '',
            description: ''
        });

        this.project = data;

        if (this.project) {
            this.form.setValue({
                name: this.project.name,
                description: this.project.description
            });
        }
    }

    save() {
        if (this.project) {
            this.project.name = this.form.value.name;
            this.project.description = this.form.value.description;

            this.projectService.updateProjectById(this.project.id, this.project).subscribe(() => {
                this.dialogRef.close();
            });
        } else {
            this.project = { // тут ошибка
                name: this.form.value.name,
                description: this.form.value.description
            };

            this.projectService.createProject(this.project).subscribe(result => {
                this.dialogRef.close(result);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
error TS2322: Type '{ name: any; description: any; }' is not assignable to type 'Project'.
  Property 'id' is missing in type '{ name: any; description: any; }'.
```

[image: Ошибка TS2322 Angular]

Comment: вы смеетесь? там же написано, что у вас два несовместимых типа из-за отсутствующего свойства

Answer (score 0):

1) Если хотите заменить значение `this.project` на новый объект только с двумя полями, то исправьте интерфейс так:

```
export interface Project {
    id?: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    created?: string;
    updated?: string;
    requests?: Request[];
}
```

2) Если хотите изменить только значения полей `name` и `description`, то пишите так

```
 this.project = { 
     ...this.project
     name: this.form.value.name,
     description: this.form.value.description
 };
```

Comment: Спасибо попробую, но я думал что помечать знаком `?` необязательные поля нужно лишь в классе, а не в интерфейсе, или я что то натупил ?